# Add to Front of an Array JQuery

Tags: jquery, arrays, addition

Basically I have an input box (*#status*) and a submit button (*.btn*) and when I type something in the input and hit the button, I want the value of what I typed to be added to the front of an array (*.unshift(...)*). The only problem is that, let's say I type "hello", that is correctly added as appendedElements = ["hello"]; but then if I type "bye", instead of having appendedElements = ["bye","hello"];, it just displays ["bye"]; and so forth

Here is my code:

```
 $('.btn').click(function(){

            var statusInput = $('#status').val();
            var appendedElements = [];

            appendedElements.unshift(statusInput); 
            console.log(appendedElements);

 });
```

I hope I was clear enough, thank you!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem is that every time on click array is reinitialized,so you will always have one item in the array.

you have to make it global:

```
var appendedElements = [];

$('.btn').click(function(){
    var statusInput = $('#status').val();
    appendedElements.unshift(statusInput); 
    console.log(appendedElements);

 });
```

Comment: .unshift is the same as push but it adds to the front instead. I've tried .push before. I will try making it global tho thank you I think that might work.

Comment: @NotToBrag see the edit, the problem is array is reinitialized every time so previous item are gone

Comment: yup, thank you Ehsan! I will accept you're answer when the time limit is over.